# Solving multiple equations with different values

Tags: equation-solving

I need to find x for this equation: a^x=b^x+c^x
I import data by this commands:

```
a = Import[
  "C:\\***\\a.xlsx"]
b = Import[
  "C:\\***\\b.xlsx"]
c = Import[
  "C:\\***\\c.xlsx"]
```

Then solving by:

```
Solve[a^x == b^x + c^x, x]
```

But there's no output

Comment: are you sure it is `a^x == b^x + c^x` and not `x^a == x^b + x^c`?  Mathematica can't solve `Solve[1^x == 2^x + 3^x, x]` for example.

Comment: Do `a`, `b`, `c` import correctly? It would help if you would include what the values of `a`, `b`, `c` wind up being, perhaps by copy-pasting their output!